# Do I need to insert one fake row in database?

Tags: database, openid

I have few tables like example.

```
Users    Books    UsersBookPurchase
UID      BookId   UserId 
UName    Name     BookId
Password Price
Email
```

This is fine. I am having my own login system but i am also using some 3rd party to validate like OpenID or facebook Authetication. My question is if the user is able to log in successfully using OpenID or facebook Authentication, what steps do i need to do i.e do i have to insert one fake row in Users table because if i do not insert how will integrity be maintained. I mean what user id should i insert in UsersBookPurchase when the person who has logged in using Facebook Authentication has made a purchase because the UserId is reference key from Users table. Please give me a high level overview of what i need to do because this is fairly common scenario.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yes. Don't think of it as a fake row. What you should do is to create an actual user account based on the data provided by Facebook API (I am not that familiar with OpenID)

Facebook API will provide you with first and last name, email address, maybe some other data
Facebook does not have the concept of login name, users login by email address.

What you do is just create a new user from the data provided by API.

There are some things to watchout for: it is possible that user is already registered on your site. When you get data from Facebook you should search your own user table to see if the email address already belongs to your own registered user and it that case you can do some fancy things like mark that user as also having a facebook login.

Comment: Beat me to it -- basically what I was going to say :-) +1 for mentioning linking accounts...

Comment: - I am using Facebook only for Authentication. But i am not getting email address in response. I do get first name and last name. But as far as email address is concerned there are 2 field namely email_hashes and proxied_email and both are null. Any ideas what can be the problem? Though this is offtrack and should really be asking a separate question because you have already answered my question as per my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do that, I'd abstracted login info into a separate table and have some sort of type in the User table. The type is used to identify what auth method is used, i.e. your own, Google, etc. If a user does select using alternative methods, you do need to have association but with a different type. But yes it is a new record.